# Travis/Jest: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of object '#<process>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, travis-ci

All my `jest` `typescript` tests fail in my `travis` pipeline throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of object '#<process>'
```

This happened suddenly without me changing anything particular in the code. And locally everything works fine.

Any ideas what could be happening ?

Comment: I just got the exact same error out of the blue in all of my builds.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That is a bug that came with node v11.11. You can downgrade to v11.10 or wait for the fix which facebook has already pushed ([jest error in Node version over 11.11](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6591)).

If your problem is TravisCI related then you can set a fixed version which works:

```
node_js:
  - "11.10.1"
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Thanks it works for me.

Answer (score 20):

You can also upgrade your version of `jest` to 24.3.0 which has this issue fixed. I believe this is a more future proof solution than downgrading your node.

Comment: I upgraded to jest 24.3.1 and it did not work.
Changed node version to 11.10.1 and it started working again

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed for me by just upgrading node to v11.12.0

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who can't fix the problem with either of the above answers, try upgrading your jest to ^24.3.0 and downgrading the node version in your docker image of your client container. I used `FROM node:11.10-alpine` without downgrading the version of node TravisCI uses.

Answer (score 1):

There were mainly two solutions for this problem

- Upgrade your jest version to 24.3.0 ( which didn't worked for me)
- Downgrade your node version to 11.10.1

I know that downgrading node version is not a good solution but for those who want to run your tests anyways can try it. By downgrading their node version from 11.11.1 to 11.10.1
Install package call "n" . 
This n package helps you to  Interactively Manage Your Node.js Versions

```
npm install -g  n
```

After installing it you just run

```
sudo n 11.10.1
```

and your node version will get changed you can check the node version by running

```
node --version
```

And later can run there test

```
npm test
```

It worked for me
I hope it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use nvm (node version manager),

```
nvm install v11
```

```
nvm use v11
```